# MS Access '16 - Query not pulling a value from a field

Tags: vba, ms-access

[Disclaimer: I'm self-taught and a total novice!]

I have a FORM with which a QUERY pulls data and uses it to populate a REPORT. As the end user finishes the report and clicks a button, the following is supposed to happen:

1) The FORM saves all the data in a new record on the TABLE 
 2) A query pulls that record by the ID (which is autonumbered) from the FORM 
 3) The QUERY populates a REPORT with the data from the TABLE 
 4) The FORM and QUERY close - no need to save.

The QUERY pulls all the data from the corresponding TABLE with the following criteria: [Forms]![Data_Input_Form]![ID]

However, my REPORT comes up blank! Eek!

I have a similar QUERY that pulls data from the same TABLE and populates it to a similar REPORT with the following criteria: Like Nz([Forms]![Home_Form]![Incident_ID_Lookup_text],"*")

Unsurprisingly, when I added this to the QUERY that wasn't working how I wanted it to, it reported ALL the previous records.

```
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Add Report [and Open Report] Button Click
'
'
'------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub Add_Rpt_Btn_Click()

If MsgBox("Are you sure? No backsies.", vbYesNo, "Add Report?") = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If

 'Check for Necessary Fields and Add New Record
If (IsNull(Me.Person_Filing) Or IsNull(Me.Nature_Lst) Or IsNull(Me.Location_Cmb) Or IsNull(Me.Summary) Or IsNull(Me.Narrative)) = True Then
    MsgBox "Looks like you left some important information out. Please fill out all fields with an asterisk.", vbOKOnly, Whoops
    Exit Sub
Else
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End If

 'Run Query to Open Report
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Form_to_Report_Qry"

DoCmd.OpenReport "Incident_Report_1", acViewReport, , [ID] = [Forms]![Data_Input_Form]![ID]

 'Close Query without Saving
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Form_to_Report_Qry", acSaveNo

 'Close Form without Saving
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Data_Input_Form", acSaveNo

End Sub
```

The REPORT needs to populate with the most recent record, but it keeps coming up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you move a new (empty) record - having no ID.

I guess, all you need is to use the current ID of the form - and use the correct syntax for the filter:

```
Private Sub Add_Rpt_Btn_Click()

    If MsgBox("Are you sure? No backsies.", vbYesNo, "Add Report?") = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Check for Necessary Fields and Add New Record
    If (IsNull(Me.Person_Filing) Or IsNull(Me.Nature_Lst) Or IsNull(Me.Location_Cmb) Or IsNull(Me.Summary) Or IsNull(Me.Narrative)) = True Then
        MsgBox "Looks like you left some important information out. Please fill out all fields with an asterisk.", vbOKOnly, Whoops
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' If not saved, save the current record.
    If Me.Dirty = True Then
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If

    DoCmd.OpenReport "Incident_Report_1", acViewReport, , "[ID] = " & Me![ID].Value & ""

    ' Close Form without Saving
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo

End Sub
```

Comment: Awww yeah! Thanks, Gustav, that totally worked. Can you explain (or link to an explanation) this bit:

"[ID] = " & Me![ID].Value & ""

And thanks again! I was way stumped!

Comment: It is the filter expression that - when the report opens - filters the report on this single record.